# Edit uploaded files as local file

Tags: file, web, edit

We have an application which accepts user submitted files (email attachments and an upload form), and the list of files is displayed to the users.

I would like to able to allow users to directly edit the files over the internet without having to have a mapped drive or 3rd party software like cloudberry to the remote storage. Currently the users have to download, edit and re-upload which is not great.

I had been considering sharepoint online and mapping a drive to the document library for the windows users, which is ok, but will require the mappings to be setup for every user and does not work natively for mac users, is there another/better way to achieve this?

Thanks

Rob

Comment: Would ftp be a option?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but with FTP would they not need to download the file edit it and then re-upload the file?

Comment: They could use a ftp 'browser', as example the normal windows file explorer and they could edit the files in place.